# Why am I getting a "DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" error?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to experiment with the python library scrapy and have run into an issue. I am following a small tutorial on [Python Application Development Using Scrapy](https://boostlog.io/@bily809/python-application-development-using-scrapy-5b309cbe44deba0054046cd0) and using this code

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"
start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/',
]

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
        yield {
            'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
            'author': quote.xpath('span/small/text()').extract_first(),
        }

    next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr("href")').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

I run it using the command `scrapy runspider quotes_spider.py -o quotes.json` and I am presented with this output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from scrapy.http import Request
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 11, in <module>
import lxml.html
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Why am I receiving these errors?

I am using a 64-Bit version of Python 2.7 and I think scrapy is 64-bit as well but I am not entirely sure. Any help with this would be appreciated!

**Edit:** Deleting the lxml libraries and reinstalling them was my fix for this particular issue

Comment: This error usually means that either the `lxml` binary extension module, or the `libxml2` C library that it depends on, is 32-bit rather than 64-bit. On Windows, usually you install `lxml` via `pip` from a binary wheel that comes with its own linked-in `libxml2`, but in the old days, when people used to download and run separate installers for each package on Windows, this was pretty common. Could that be relevant here?

Comment: Potentially. I will look more into that and give it a shot. I haven't heard of either of those yet so it could a fix. Thanks!

Comment: @abarnert uninstalling and reinstalling the lxml binary module seemed to get rid of my problem. But unfortunately another error happened. The joys of programming :)